# ESS ignores R_LIBS_USER environment variable

Tags: ess, r

I have the following in my `.bashrc`

```
export R_LIBS_USER="/home/wdkrnls/R/lib/3.2"
```

When I start `R` from the shell I see (even in Emacs `M-x shell`):

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/wdkrnls/R/lib/3.2"  "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

When I start an `R` process with `M-x R`, I see:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

How do I make `ESS` know about and use official R environment variables instead of ignoring them?

Comment: You'd also need to add `(setenv "R_LIBS_USER" "/home/wdkrnls/R/lib/3.2")` to your Emacs init file. In general, this is related to how environment variables are inherited by programs. Most likely you are running Emacs from shell that does not read that `.bashrc`. There are also Emacs packages that parse environment variables from shell started from current user account and add them to Emacs environment, but I cannot remember the name at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following, @wvxvw's comment: I was starting Emacs from an environment which wasn't executing my .bashrc.